# How to know in android if the map is loaded completely programmatically?

Tags: google-maps

I am loading a map in a mapview and i am capturing the map from the view and sending the image through email in my app. However i want to capture the image only if it is loaded completely in my view. Is there a mechanism in android to know the state.

thanks in advance

Comment: There is a `tilesloaded` event of the google maps which fires which the map is completely loaded.

Comment: tilesloaded is not for Android i am loading the map in MapActivity